# sentiment analysis api language Russian in C#

Tags: .net, api, sentiment-analysis

can you advise the API for use in my project on the following criteria: 
1. .Net 
2. Russian Language 
3. Paid or free version - it does not matter 
Looked at a large number of API, but could not find satisfying all the criteria listed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alachemy API,

AlchemyAPI can be easily used with any major programming language: Java, C/C++, C#, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, Javascript and Android OS

Providing link below:

[Alchemy Api](http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/sdks/)
SDK has test classes as well for understanding purpose.

Answer (score 0):

At SemanticAnalyzer we have exactly what you need: sentiment analysis of a text in Russian. Shipped both as a library and an API. Supports both Java and C# (library) and any language (API):

API on mashape:

https://www.mashape.com/dmitrykey/russiansentimentanalyzer
https://www.mashape.com/dmitrykey/sentifindr

Answer (score 0):

In April 2018, there's at least 3 Sentiment Analysis for Russian:

- [IBM Watson NLU](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/natural-language-understanding/)
- [Microsoft Cognitive Services Text Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/)
- [Repustate Text Analytics](https://www.repustate.com/text-analytics-api/)

They vastly differ in features and pricing. I would rever [to this article for the detailed comparison](https://blog.inten.to/cloud-sentiment-analysis-vendor-overview-32d4bdaaf0c3). Also, you may [play with this API](https://github.com/intento/intento-api/blob/master/ai.text.sentiment.md) to access all those SA services via a single integration.